# Cypress installation failed

Tags: node.js, installation, cypress

I installed nodejs and npm on windows 10. Than I tried to install cypress via  `npm install cypress --save-dev` and get the following Error:

```
> node index.js --exec install

The command "node" is either misspelled or
could not be found.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! cypress@3.8.2 postinstall: `node index.js --exec install`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the cypress@3.8.2 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\U\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-01-21T11_05_01_566Z-debug.log
```

After this I added the path `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp` to my system environment variables. But I get this error messages again. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Seems like `node` is not available in your $PATH.

Which output do you get when you run `node -v` ?

Comment: i get [v13.6.0] and when i run [npm -v] i get [6.13.6]

Answer (score 2):

try the following steps :

1. install git on your machine and config it as global.
2. delete old package.js then re-init new package.
3. try again cypress install command

Answer (score 2):

**Download it in the any directory**  its a hack to download, if your proxy is properly configured and internet speed is good. it will download while doing npm install

```
wget https://cdn.cypress.io/desktop/7.6.0/win32-x64/cypress.zip
```

Provide the zip location

```
CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY=~/Downloads/cypress.zip npm install cypress
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead by installing the previous version but Explicitly: `npm install cypress@8.1.0 --save-dev`

Answer (score 0):

Remember to actually run the npm command inside your folder with the package.json.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Note: answers that are very brief and/or are questions back to the poster should probably be comments. If you do not have enough reputation to comment on posts, stick to posting answers that actually provide an answer to the question.

Answer (score -2):

Delete the package.json.

Again re build the package by `npm init`.

Install Cypress again by using `npm install cypress --save-dev`.